# Move div based on height div up to him

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am working on information banners. There are few `div`s on top of each other with a hover mask on them. On hover they change their text. Sometimes the hover text will be longer than the parent, the `div` below the hovered one should move under the hover text.

```css
div.quick-banner {
  width: 440px;
  margin: 0 0 0 15px;
  position: relative;
}
div.quick-banner div.mask-banner {
  width: 420px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
div.quick-banner div.mask-banner h2 {
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   font-size: 17px;
   padding: 3px;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   margin: 0;
}
div.quick-banner div.mask-banner {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   background-color: #004f6e;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
div.quick-banner:hover div.mask-banner {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
}
div.quick-banner div.mask-banner h2 {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-100px);
   -o-transform: translateY(-100px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-100px);
   transform: translateY(-100px);
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
div.quick-banner div.mask-banner:hover h2,
div.quick-banner div.mask-banner:hover p,
div.quick-banner div.mask-banner:hover a.info {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
   -o-transform: translateY(0px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
   transform: translateY(0px);
}
div.quick-banner div.mask-banner p {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(100px);
   -o-transform: translateY(100px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(100px);
   transform: translateY(100px);
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="quick-banner">
    <div class="main-banner">
        <h2>Head 1</h2>
        <p>This is first text of first banner.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mask-banner">
        <h2>Head HOVER 1</h2>
        <p>Text after hover longer (3-5 rows). Text after hover       longer (3-5 rows). Text after hover longer (3-5 rows). Text after hover longer (3-5 rows)</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="quick-banner">
    <div class="main-banner">
        <h2>Head 2</h2>
        <p>This is first text of first banner.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mask-banner">
        <h2>Head HOVER 2</h2>
        <p>Text after hover longer (3-5 rows). Text after hover       longer (3-5 rows). Text after hover longer (3-5 rows). Text after hover longer (3-5 rows)</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

On hover I change the opacity of main and mask banner, which is working but the second `div` is appearing over the hovered text. 
Is there a solution (pure CSS would be best) to move the next `div` under the hover `div` based on relative height of the hover text?

Comment: Can you put a simple fiddle together so that we can take a look?

Comment: Yes i put it on fiddle, i made there some mistake, but point is that i need second banner to move under first after i hover first. http://jsfiddle.net/r1yk5on3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use `position: absolute;` for `.mask-banner` as it will take it out of the document flow and the other elements will not be aware of it. You can get round this by:

- Moving the `hover` detection to the parent `.quick-banner`
- Keeping `.mask-banner` in the flow (don't use `position: absolute;`)
- Hide the content of `.main-banner` when `.quick-banner` is hovered

To keep the animation intact you won't be able to hide `mask-banner` using `display: none;` so you can do this by using `height: 0;` and `overflow: hidden;` instead.

```css
div.quick-banner {
    width: 440px;
    margin: 0 0 0 15px;
    position: relative;
}
div.quick-banner div.mask-banner {
    width: 420px;
    position: relative; /*Change this*/
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0; /*Change this*/
    text-align: center;
    height: 0; /*Add this*/
    overflow: hidden; /*Add this*/
}
div.quick-banner div.mask-banner h2 {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 3px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    margin: 0;
}
div.quick-banner div.mask-banner {
    -ms-filter:"progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #004f6e;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
div.quick-banner:hover div.mask-banner {
    -ms-filter:"progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto; /*Add this*/
    padding: 10px; /*Add this*/
}
div.quick-banner div.mask-banner h2 {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100px);
    -o-transform: translateY(-100px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100px);
    transform: translateY(-100px);
    -ms-filter:"progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
/*Change this*/
div.quick-banner:hover div.mask-banner h2, div.quick-banner:hover div.mask-banner p, div.quick-banner:hover div.mask-banner a.info {
    -ms-filter:"progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -o-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
}
div.quick-banner div.mask-banner p {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(100px);
    -o-transform: translateY(100px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(100px);
    transform: translateY(100px);
    -ms-filter:"progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
/*Add this*/
div.quick-banner:hover div.main-banner {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="quick-banner">
    <div class="main-banner">
         <h2>Head 1</h2>

        <p>This is first text of first banner.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mask-banner">
         <h2>Head HOVER 1</h2>

        <p>Text after hover longer (3-5 rows). Text after hover longer (3-5 rows). Text after hover longer (3-5 rows). Text after hover longer (3-5 rows)</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="quick-banner">
    <div class="main-banner">
         <h2>Head 2</h2>

        <p>This is first text of first banner.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mask-banner">
         <h2>Head HOVER 2</h2>

        <p>Text after hover longer (3-5 rows). Text after hover longer (3-5 rows). Text after hover longer (3-5 rows). Text after hover longer (3-5 rows)</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/xtfzgrcm/2/

Comment: Thank you, thats perfetct, now i am trying to animate that change of height of 0 to auto, but transition: height 0.3s ease-out; and ease-in not working... Some tips?

Comment: Unfortunately animating `height` when you don't know how high the content is is a bit tricky. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/css-transition-height-0-to-height-auto may be able to help you in that regard. You'll have to experiment, but in this case animating `height` may cause issues with the hover effect as `.quick-banner`'s `height` is determined by its content.